# Oracle - Joining a inline table or table on the fly

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem where a validation Code is stored in my table along with other data. Unfortunately the description is stored in a table where  I dont have access to. I do know the values

Example

[image]

12, 14, and 22- Description for them is available in an excel. I have no permissions to create a table to store the data and I need to run them every day as a reporting work.

- 12- Missing Work
- 14 - Absent
- 22 - Incomplete

Question: how do I write a query where I can create a dummy table(inline? On the fly?) with the values in excel and join to my table so that results looks like this

[image]

Note:

- I cant create a perm table - no permissions. Its a read only Db for me
- I want to give 12,MissingWork, 14, Absent as part of my query

Any thoughts. I tried searching. I think I am not using the right terminology and hence not finding results.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by joining a subquery that `SELECT`s each code description pair `FROM dual` and uses `UNION ALL` to combine their results into one set.

```
SELECT t1.date,
       t1.task,
       t1.code,
       x.description
       FROM table1 t1
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT 12 code,
                              'Missing Work' description
                              FROM dual
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT 14 code,
                              'Absent' description
                              FROM dual
                       ...) x
                      ON x.code = t1.code;
```

Answer (score 1):

As you know those codes and descriptions, a simple option is to create a CTE; in the following example, it is called `excel`. Another CTE in this example represents your "real" `table1` (I could have created it in my database, but CTE is good enough to show what to do).

```
SQL> with excel (code, description) as
  2    (select 12, 'Missing Work' from dual union all
  3     select 14, 'Absent'       from dual union all
  4     select 22, 'Incomplete'   from dual
  5    ),
  6    table1 (c_date, task, code) as
  7    (select date '2019-05-30', 'Homework', 12 from dual union all
  8     select date '2019-05-31', 'Labwork' , 14 from dual union all
  9     select date '2019-05-30', 'Other'   , 22 from dual
 10    )
 11  select t.c_date, t.task, t.code, e.description
 12  from table1 t join excel e on e.code = t.code;

C_DATE     TASK           CODE DESCRIPTION
---------- -------- ---------- ------------
05/30/2019 Homework         12 Missing Work
05/31/2019 Labwork          14 Absent
05/30/2019 Other            22 Incomplete

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something called Common Table Expressions (CTE)

```
WITH Code_lookup AS (
  SELECT 12 Code, 'Missing Work' Description FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 14, 'Absent' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 22, 'Incomplete' FROM DUAL)
SELECT <your columns list>
  FROM <your table>
  JOIN Code_lookup USING (Code)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use a common table expression with a union:

```
with descr (code, description) as (
    select 12, 'Missing Work' from dual union
    select 14, 'Absent' from dual union
    select 22, 'Incomplete' from dual
)
select table1.date, table1.task, table1.code, descr.description
from table1
left join descr on table1.code = descr.code
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle there is a DECODE function that would be suitable.

```
select code,
       DECODE(code, 12, 'Missing work',
                    14, 'Absent'
                    22, 'Incomplete',
                    'UNKNOWN Code) as Description
from table;
```

The first argument is the field to decode, followed by pairs of values for the mapping, and a final value which is the decoded value when there is no match.
You code use a CTE and distinct to turn it into a proper table if that's what's needed.  Then you would have the decode in a single place and wouldn't have to inline it everywhere.